# Cornerstone is messing up a file

Tags: macos, svn, version-control, cornerstone

I have just checked out a branch from a repo and there's one file that's showing as not found (! icon) and as new (? icon), one entry below the other.

No matter what I do the file keeps showing like this.

Neither reverting to the latest in repo will solve the problem.

Does anyone knows anything about it?

[image: Cornerstone file conflict]

Comment: Can you please try to delete the folder from the Finder and then in CornerStone right click the project and update to latest.

Comment: First thing I did. Got the same result. I sorted out removing the file (saving it first) and adding it again (2 commits) but I would like people commenting on this as the issue is weird and absurd. Thanks.